# error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' . How to provide an input for a search index?

Tags: c++, arrays

My assignment is to hardcode an integer array, display the array to the user, and then ask the user to input an integer to search for. My problem is getting the input to search the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

{

int intArray [17] = {7, 3, 32, 2, 55, 34, 6, 13,29,22, 11, 9, 1, 5,42,39, 8};

cout << "List = 7, 3, 32, 2, 55, 34, 6, 13,29,22, 11, 9, 1, 5,42,39, 8 " << endl;

cout << "Enter an integer in the list to search for: " << endl;
cin >> intArray;

}
```

Comment: Try creating a new variable to read the input. Don't read it into the same intArray.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that there is no function that supports the call.

```
cin >> intArray;
```

Looking at the previous line in your code, that is not what you should be doing anyway. You need something like:

```
int numberToLookFor;
cin >> numberToLookFor;
```

and then add the code to look for `numberToLookFor` in `intArray`.

Comment: My skills at C++ are pretty basic, how would I go about adding code to look for numberToLookFor in intArray?

Answer (score 0):

You can't search an array that way like R. Sahu described.

You could use a ranged base for loop where you ask for the input.

Something like this:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
for (int i : intarray)
{  
   if (i == value)
   std::cout << "Found";
}
```